# Transferir o valor de uma variavel para o ctrl+C em Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, área-de-transferência

Estou fazendo um trabalho e preciso que o valor de uma variável vá para o clipboard para que eu possa usá-la em um outro momento.

Tem como fazer isso no Python v2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar essa lib pronta, como o:

- https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

Tem suporte para Windows, Mac e Linux (em Linux requer gtk ou PyQt4)

Instalando via PIP o `pyperclip`:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
import pyperclip


variavel = "Python"

pyperclip.copy(variavel)
```

> **Nota:** internamente o https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/ usa o pyperclip, por isso removi da resposta, não há vantagem alguma em seu uso, o único motivo qual o autor criou a lib foi pra ter um "nome melhor" (talvez ele não saiba como o `import` funciona)